# How to combine try_files and sendfile on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need Nginx to serve a file relative from document root if it exists, then fallback to an upstream server if it doesn't. This can be accomplished with something like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root /var/www/nginx/;
        try_files $uri @my_upstream;
    }

    location @my_upstream {
        internal;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Fair enough. The problem is, my upstream is not serving the contents of URI directly, but instead, returning `X-Accel-Redirect` with a location relative to document root (it generates this file on-the-fly):

```
% curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/animals/kitten.jpg__100x100__crop.jpg
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2012 20:58:25 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2
X-Accel-Redirect: animals/kitten.jpg__100x100__crop.jpg
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Apparently, this should work. The problem though is that Nginx tries to serve this file from some internal default document root instead of using the one specified in the `location` block:

```
2012/11/26 18:44:55 [error] 824#0: *54 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.4/htmlanimals/kitten.jpg__100x100__crop.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /animals/kitten.jpg__100x100__crop.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/animals/kitten.jpg__100x100__crop.jpg", host: "127.0.0.1:80"
```

How do I force Nginx to serve the file relative to the right document root? According to [XSendfile documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) the returned path should be relative, so my upstream is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your `root` directive under `server`, and not under `location`. This is one of the most [common nginx configuration mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `root` rule to the `server` block and it *almost* worked. I had to change my upstream to return an URI starting with a slash, apparently Nginx ignored the last slash in the `root` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your backend produces incorrect `X-Accel-Redirect` header: the path part of URI must start with `/` (see RFC 3986).

Comment: Yep, figured it out.